# How can I handle the flow of Amplify.federatedSignIn?

Tags: authentication, aws-amplify

What I want is redirect user to guide page of my app only when user first sign in with google(or facebook).
if he aleady signed before, he should be redirected to main page.

But I don't know how distinguish whether he is first sign in or not in Amplify federatedSignIn

Also I don't know how I can have multiple redirect url with condition after federatedSignIn success

Do you have any suggesstion for me?